# axis labels styling - Angular NVD3 - Line chart

Tags: angularjs, linechart, angularjs-nvd3-directives, angular-nvd3

usage - Angular NVD3
LineChart

I am getting `milliseconds`, converting them to `('%H:%M')` format to display on x-axis.

```
 xAxis: {
          tickFormat: function(d) {
          return d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
        },
```

The above works fine, and shows data in format `10:30`.

i need to format it's styling, `10:` in different color and `30` in different.

**I wrote below Javascript,**

```
 xAxis: {
          axisLabel: '',
          tickFormat: function(d) {
          var xlabel =  d3.time.format('%H:%M')(new Date(d));
          var xlabelB = xlabel.substring(0, 3);
          var xlabelA = xlabel.substring(3, 5);
          var text = '<span class="lightText">'+ xlabelB + '</span><span class="boldText">' + xlabelA + '</span>';
                            console.log(text);
                            return text;
     },
```

But the above is rendered inside `<Text> tag`, so it does not render html.

How can i achieve the same. Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WmnP9CApQ6Mj19aHFePL?p=preview)

**Here is the generated html after formatting,**

```
<text dy=".71em" y="10" transform="" style="text-anchor: middle;"><span class="lightText">10:</span><span class="boldText">30</span></text>
```

**Before Formatting**

```
<text dy=".71em" y="10" transform="" style="text-anchor: middle;">10:30</text>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean to use tspan within text tags? Using tspan will allow you to format text separately like this example below

```html
<svg>
  <g>
    <text dy=".71em" y="10" x="0" transform="" style="text-anchor: left;">
      <tspan style="fill:red;">10:</tspan>
      <tspan style="font-weight:bold;">30</tspan>
    </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Although, you would not be able to use html using the tickFormat function for axes. You would have to get handle of the chart (using d3) and build your own axis, I believe.